# Why is the first Goldie theorem true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The first Goldie theorem says that if $R$ is an order in a simple Artinian ring, then $R$ is a prime Goldie ring.

This should be an immediate consequence of the second Goldie theorem which asserts:

A ring R is semiprime goldie iff R is an ore ring and an order in a semisimple ring.

I can see that from this follows that $R$ is a semiprime Goldie ring but I don't see why $R$ is prime.

I tried to lifts ideals of $R$ to the left localisation $S^{-1}R$ but this didn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems clear to me that if $e$ is a nontrivial central idempotent of $R$, then $(1, e)$ is automatically a nontrivial central idempotent of the left classical ring of quotients.

Therefore $R$ has no such idempotents, and is simple.

Comment: Yes I managed to show that if $Q$ is simple and the localisation of $R$ w.r.t. regular elements, then $R$ must be prime with a straightforward proof (take two right ideals $V,W$ with $VW=0$ and $W\neq 0$. Then because $Q$ is simple $QWQ=Q$ and we get the equation $1=\sum p_i w_i q_i$. Putting the $p_i's$ on common denominator and multiplying with this denominator we get $s=\sum r_i V_i q_i$ where $r_i\in qr$ and multiplying with $L$ we get $Vs=0$. Since $s$ is regular, we conclude $V=0$.